# XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Origin http://localhost:63342 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://192.168.3.140:8081/SamplengcordovaApp/Savedata.php',
    data: resdata,
    dataType: "json"
  })
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;
                alert(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert(status);
        });
```

getting the success but not saved in database.please provide the supported code for me.

Comment: Then check on server side is data received or not?

Comment: in server side saving the data  in client side not saving

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem.

You are making an ajax request from a page of different domain. which is not allowed.

To allow it you will have to append `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header of the server page by adding this on the top of the server page

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Note: the '*' at the end means it will accept any request from any website, for added security you could do this

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourwebsite.com');
```

Comment: same problem again

Comment: trying adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');`